# how to show a polynomial inequality

Tags: polynomials

How to show something like this?

$$ \frac{[1-(1-p)^n]^2}{np} > 1- (1-p)^n - \frac{n-1}{n} [1-(1-p)^{n-1}]$$
where $0<p<1$, and $n \geq 2$ is an integer.

Comment: Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It makes me think of probability. Maybe you can find some distribution which has some property it matches.

Comment: @mathreadler thanks and yes binomial distribution. But still not clear how to proceed

Comment: Maybe the binomial theorem can help, then. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: @mathreadler yes it can.... just need to find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try for a solution. Put $q=1-p$. You want to show $$\frac{(1-q^n)^2}{1-q} \geq 1+(n-1)q^{n-1}-nq^n$$
We have:
$$(n-1)q^{n-1}\leq q+\cdots+q^{n-1}$$
and
$$ q^n+\cdots+q^{2n-1}\leq nq^n$$
Hence:
$$1+(n-1)q^{n-1}-nq^n\leq 1+(q+\cdots+q^{n-1})-(q^n+\cdots+q^{2n-1})=(1-q^n)(1+\cdots+q^{n-1})$$
and we are done.

Comment: This is great!!